# npmrc private package authentication failing in Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, digital-ocean

I have a Docker container that works perfectly in local development, but when I push it to my DigitalOcean App Platform, I always get the following error with one of my private packages:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@org/utils/-/utils-1.2.4.tgz - Not found
npm ERR! 404 '@org/utils@https://registry.npmjs.org/@org/utils/-/utils-1.2.4.tgz' is not in this registry.
```

---

**Dockerfile** (`/Dockerfile`):

```
// ...FIRST STAGE...

FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

// I set this inside of DigitalOcean's environment variables.
ARG NPM_TOKEN

COPY package*.json /app/

// SEE: alexandraulsh.com/2018/06/25/docker-npmrc-security/#solution---multi-stage-builds
RUN echo "//registry.npmjs.org/:authToken=$NPM_TOKEN" > .npmrc && \
    npm ci --production --no-audit && \
    rm -f .npmrc
RUN npm cache clean --force

COPY . /app/

RUN npm run build

// ...SECOND STAGE...

FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/.dist /app/.dist
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json /app/package.json
COPY --from=builder /app/package-lock.json /app/package-lock.json
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules /app/node_modules

EXPOSE 4000
ENV PORT 4000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "./.dist/src/Main.js"]
```

**npmrc** (`/.npmrc`):

```
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

Additionally, I've tried following the [following article](https://docs.npmjs.com/docker-and-private-modules) from NPM themselves to no avail.